# ffmpeg output file size grows faster than linearly with movie length

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to string together some .bmp images into a movie. In total, there are 1001 frames, amounting to 0:40 length. The command I'm using is

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i render.%05d.bmp -c:v libx264 -s 512:268 render.mp4
```

The output file is 33,2 MB large, which is about twice the size of a full HD (about 16 times the pixels!) video of the same length. Apart from the file size being unreasonably large, I realized it grows faster than linearly (can't tell exactly if it is quadratic, exponential etc.) with the number of frames. After 100 frames it is about 1536 KB large (which is already too large), after 500 frames it is already 15104 KB, and after 1001 it finally arrives at 34085 KB.

My educated guess would be that for each frame it stores some information about all of the previous frames again, which makes absolutely no sense.

What am I doing wrong? Before you recommend libx265 to me: It turns the entire video green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
ffmpeg -i render.%05d.bmp -c:v libx264 -vf "scale=512:-2,format=yuv420p" -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- If the output file size is too big add the `-crf` and `-preset` options as described in [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).
- If the output is still too big change `-c:v libx264` to `-c:v libx265` but encoding will be slower. Your output was green when you tried x265 because of the pixel format: using `format=yuv420p` as shown in my example will fix that. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.265](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265).
- If you are targeting a specific output file size then use two-passes with `-b:v` (see either link above).

Comment: This doesn't really stop the weird "exploding size" phenomenon (on second thought, this might also be a display error), and the files are still unexpectedly large. But it definitely reduces file size to a workable level. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @JakobFilser To overly simplify I'm guessing the initial frames were simpler, and the later ones were more complex, so the complex frames received more bits. If it's still unexpectedly large use a higher `-crf` value or perform two-pass encoding if you need the output to be below a certain size.